# Intervals of increase and decrease

Tags: calculus

If you have a function and there's an asymptote at say -7, then when doing the intervals for increase decrease, would you do something like increasing from $(-\infty,-7)\cup(-7,\text{wherever increase stops})$ and not include the $-7$, or would the $-7$ be included

Answer (score 1):

The given interval does not include $-7$.   It is a limit point.

If you don't want to include $-7$ in the interval, then that is a way to express it.

$$(-\infty; -7)\cup(-7;x_{\max}] \;\equiv\; (-\infty;x_{max}]\setminus\{-7\}$$